# Sublime Text 2 - Error downloading package control at my work

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

when i try install package from package control (by <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + p</kbd>) i get some error:

> Package Control There are no package available for installation

and in the Sublime Text Console i get:

> Package Control: Error downloading channel. URL error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/repositories.json.
>   error: Package Control: There are no packages available for installation.

1. I can enter directly and see the repositores.json in my browser.
2. at my home Sublime Text Work perfect BUT at my work i have the issue above.

What I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy when using your web browser?

Comment: Are you sure non-http protocols are enabled in your office network? I can't make package controller (nor Transmission, i.e.) work at my university.

Comment: The Issue was proxy. after i add the proxy attribute with correct prxoy of my Job it worl well. Thanks